# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0x010db93e38)

Tags: ios, swift

[This is the crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85phc.png) Every time I click on the button that is a part of the simulator, I keep getting the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. This code is the part of the calendar from the JTAppleCalendar.

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class EventsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCalendarView()

    }
    func setupCalendarView(){
        calendarView.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        calendarView.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an error message in logs?

Comment: self=(CCAID.EventsViewController) 0x00007f91c6c43250

Comment: There is 1. No question and 2. No useful information (i.e. the actual crash message). @PraneethKandula not that, from the console

Comment: the error just crashes at 11db

Comment: paste your crash logs please.

Comment: I added an image of the crash logs

Comment: I missed your response. I hope your problem is resolved by now. But your logs show nothing about the calendar :/

Answer (score 0):

Check if calendarView is connected in the Storyboard in Referencing Outlets.

Comment: I checked and I believe it is